# Convert rear hub width 142 mm to fit 135 mm dropouts

Tags: mountain-bike

I recently bought a pair of Shimano XT Deore wheels. I then realized they cannot fit my MTB hardtail dropouts.

Is there any way to convert an MTB rear wheel with hub width 142 mm to 135 mm?

Comment: If the hubs weren't Shimano, you might have had a chance to source a conversion kit, but I think Shimano doesn't make those because the hubs use cup and cone bearings.

Answer (score 4):

You've made a bad purchase by not checking the specs.

If these are brand new from a shop, you may have a limited time when you can return them for a full refund.  The time window will depend where in the world you are.

If you bought them used/second hand or more than a month ago, you're stuck with them.  Either resell them on ebay or similar, or look at your other bikes to see if they will fit.

Another option is to buy a frame that does fit these wheels, and build up another bike.

If your bike frame is steel then you may be able to cold-set the frame to accept the larger wheel, but this will utterly void any warranty on your bike.  If your frame is aluminium or carbon or titanium then this is not an option for you.

Answer (score -1):

I would go the other way round, i.e. converting the frame from 135 to 142mm, unless it is a carbon frame.
Simply rely on the metal deformation and follow the RJ The Bike Guy method presented here: [Upgrade Vintage 10 Speed Bike To 14 Speed & Indexed Shifting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO5V3qkW05g)

I'm sure a steel frame can have it without any drawbacks to its structure. <s>Aluminium frames are not that flexible as steel but 3.5 mm per side should be ok in my opinion.</s> However, **don't try it on an aluminium or carbon frame** - those won't handle deformations well.

EDIT: seeing the downvotes and comments I've made necessary changes.

Comment: Aluminium frames can not be cold-set like steel frames.  Don't do that.

Comment: -1. The OP's hub is most likely a 12mm TA and frame accepts 135mm QR. Those hubs are the same dropout distance, but TA dropouts have an extra 3.5mm slots.

Comment: *Absolutely not* on an aluminum frame.

Comment: Trying to hack the frame would be a nightmare. Even if the dropouts could be widened, there's the axle type to be considered as @Klaster_1 commented. Also 142mm rear hub bikes have wider bottom brackets I believe. Chainline would be way out. Return or sell the wheels. Learn the lesson.